# Including header in base.twig for all pages

Tags: symfony, twig

It is something pretty simple to be done outside of twig but here I am not even sure it is possible. This is the case:
Have `base.html.twig`. `header.html.twig`, `home.html.twig`.

```
#home.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>MY HTML</h1>
{% endblock %}


#base.html.twig
....some html here
{% block header%}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
....some more html here


#header.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block header %}
    some here things that have to shown on every page through base.html.twig
{% endblock %}
```

I think it is pretty straight forward scenario but still my header doesn't show anywhere. As I understood from the documentation it is not working because this is how blocks work. It renders the page i am calling from my controller (`home.html.twig`) and the extended by it (`base.html.twig`). But wont call the header as well. So! How should I call the header on every page ?

Comment: Write the header block content in your base directly or you could replace your header block in your base with `{% include 'header.html.twig' %}`..

Answer (score 1):

To add the header on all pages just put include see example

```
{% block header %}
    {% include 'header.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```